# mPDF use FPDI v2

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf, fpdi

I am currently using mPDF to handle a couple of things. The problem I'm facing however is that mPDF uses a version of FPDI that is unable to handle files over PDF version 1.4. There is a (paid) commercial addon that makes handling newer PDF files possible though. The problem is:

- I installed mPDF through composer.
- I am unable to change the FPDI package, since mPDF is a package in and of itself, that uses another package.

My question is: How can I change mPDF to use the commercial (v2) version of FPDI?

Thanks in advance.

~Brendan

Comment: mPDF 8.0.0-RC1 with FPDI 2 was released yesterday, feel free to test it and report possible bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this [pull request](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/pull/899), that adds compatibility for FPDI v2. Because of BC breaks it will be merged in mPDF 8.

Until that just use the legacy version of the parser add-on. This can also be installed [with composer](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser-manual/v1/installation/#index-3).